# How to open Angular modal window with selected data from table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui.bootstrap

I need to open modal window with selected data from cell of table. Now the modal is opened with data but data in modal belong to all row. I need to chose data from item selected cell. I have a two arrays. One in other. I can selected item from first array (dataTable) but there is exist another array (item.arrValues) in the there. I can't to get the selected data from a second array. How can I to display the data from selected cell?

Example here [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/F5tRKepIeKIQZFLG6SCY?p=preview)

HTML

```html
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td ng-repeat="i in  vm.dataTable[0].arrValues">{{i.DAY}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in vm.dataTable">
   <td>{{item.time}}</td>
   <td ng-click="vm.openEvents(item);" ng-repeat="i in item.arrValues">{{i.Value}}</td>
  </tr>           
 </tbody>
</table>
```

modalContent.html

```html
<div>
  
  <div class="modal-body" style="overflow: hidden;">
     
    <div ng-bind="selected.item.Country"></div>
  
    <!--<div ng-bind="selected.item.arrValues[0].Value"></div>-->
   
   <div ng-repeat="i in selected.item.arrValues">{{i.Value}}</div>
  
  </div>

</div>
```

JS

```html
vm.openEvents = function(item){
 var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  scope: $scope,//
  templateUrl: "modalContent.html",
  controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
  resolve: {
   item: function() {
    return item;
   },
    
  dataTable: function ($timeout) {
   return vm.dataTable
  }
    
 }
});
 }
  
var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, dataTable, item) {
 var vm = this;
  
 vm.dataTable = dataTable;
        
 $scope.selected = {
  item: item
 };
}
```

Comment: please only tag questions `[angularjs]` or `[angular]` unless youre using both frameworks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `<td>` to pass `i` to the function (i being the value in the cell in this case):

```
<td ng-click="vm.openEvents(i);" ng-repeat="i in item.arrValues">{{i.Value}}</td>
```

Change the modal template to display `selected.item.DAY` and `selected.item.Value`.

```
<div>
    <div class="modal-body" style="overflow: hidden;">
        <div ng-bind="selected.item.DAY"></div>
        <div ng-bind="selected.item.Value"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Working PLNKR here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/LuFsR4jHPZp8a0Wm9O4Q)